# Process SSIS Package when DateModified Changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have built an SSIS Package for our HR Department. 
The Data is manually downloaded from a web portal in .xls format.

The current process is not automated due to the inconsistent frequency of the data drop. 
What I would like to do is alter the SSIS package so that it looks at the Source data (they just save over the existing file every month) and have the Job run as soon as the "Date Modified" has changed.

I am not familiar with C# so I would like to avoid this option if possible, I am still a little new to all of this. I am hoping that there is a Loop Container option or something.

*Additional data: The Table that is loaded is truncated before the load. I don't know if this will factor in or not but I wanted to put it out there.

Comment: you want a file watcher that triggers an event upon datetime change.

Answer (score 1):

There are few approaches to accomplish this. Basically you need to implement some sort of trigger mechanism to run package when data modified has changed in source data.

1. Create a Windows service that uses WMI to detect change in date modified and launch packages.
2. You can use create package with infinite loop and schedule it through Agent Job. But please note SSIS is resource intensive so you have to plan interval for loop accordingly.
3. Set up a Table and create a trigger on the table for insert, that should execute the agent job with the sp_start_job system stored procedure. You could use Service Broker to add a new item to a queue. Then the execution of the SSIS  would not be anywhere near as problematic as calling it directly from a trigger.

Some useful articles -

[Execute SSIS package when a file is arrived at folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436377/how-to-execute-ssis-package-when-a-file-is-arrived-at-folder)

[Trigger SSIS package when files available in a Folder](http://msbimentalist.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/trigger-ssis-package-when-files-available-in-a-folder/)

[Trigger SSIS package when files available in a Folder part#2](http://msbimentalist.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/trigger-ssis-package-when-files-available-in-a-folder-part2/)

[How to Check IF File Exists In Folder [Script Task]](http://sqlage.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/ssis-how-to-check-if-file-exists-in.html)

[Trigger SSIS package](http://reachsatish.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/trigger-ssis-package-when-files.html)