# Trigger SQL Server Job by placing file in monitored folder

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, jobs, sql-agent-job

I have a number of SSIS bulk-insert jobs, based on a .csv of the correct filename existing in a specific network folder, which I manually run from SQL jobs in the SQL Server Agent.

I was wondering though if it is possible to have some sort of file-monitoring soluion which would trigger the jobs automatically when the correct file is saved in the folder

I know that this does not exist in SQL Server or SSIS functionality but wondered if anyone knew of a solution without buying extra software?

Comment: Yes you can do this check my answer in this post for one possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436377/how-to-execute-ssis-package-when-a-file-is-arrived-at-folder/21437846#21437846

Comment: Thanks very much for the response - I will look in to this!

Comment: I would strongly advise looking at @samvanga's answer on that question as well. It would be far better, far less resource intensive, to have a non-ssis process poll for file existence and only launch the package when a file is found

Comment: Ok thanks for your help - did try to search for any duplicates beforehand, but question can be worded very differently! Many Thanks!