# SSIS Package Execution when file arrived

Tags: ssis

i have one SSIS child Package which bulk load the data from a xml file to a table.

Please help me to how can i create a parent SSIS package 
which will tell my child package to execute once a file is arrived for bulk insert.

Please share your expertise....

i am new to SSIS . kindly help.

**I am using sql 2008**

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436377/how-to-execute-ssis-package-when-a-file-is-arrived-at-folder) or maybe [System Filewatcher Task](http://www.sqlis.com/post/file-watcher-task.aspx) will help you if you want to purely stay in SSIS.

Or maybe you could use SQL Server Job Agent to look for new files based on some intervall?