# File Watcher Job Using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS for ETL and I need to monitor a source folder for the source file to be arrived. When ever a file arrives I need to move that file into another location and rename the file and start executing another SSIS Package. Here we don't have an option to use use any other tool to automate the execution. We have only choice to use SQL Server, SSIS.

I need the mechanism and the logic to implement this logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by "File Watcher" you don't mean [FileSystemWatcher class in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as there wouldn't be any point in using this class if you're limited to SQL Server and SSIS (you'd need a job with forever-running SSIS package containing ScriptTask with FileSystemWatcher).

The only solution is to create two-step job. First step would contain SSIS package for reading directory content and comparing it to files history log. Second step would contain your main package and would execute only if first steps succeeds or returns value indicating that there are new files to process.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436377/how-to-execute-ssis-package-when-a-file-is-arrived-at-folder) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273593/ssis-polling-files-folder-and-trigger-etl-packages). My personal favorite way of doing it is having an *infinite loop* package. Yet another way of doing it would be to encapsulate the entire logic in an SSIS package and fire it every X minutes. Vary the value of X depending on the urgency.